# Android : can I visual activity always?

Tags: android

Please look here https://market.android.com/details?id=com.myboyfriendisageek.aircalc this activity is always above any running applications. HOw can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install this app it asks for only permission: [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW).

Comment: no, the activity is ALWAYS on the top also when the applications running, the trick is not trasparent background....

Comment: But the system alert window is an Dialog or an activity?